# How can I express half the distance between two nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I want to draw a line from node `A` half-way to node `B` in TiKZ. How can I find express the end point?

Comment: This is described in section `13.5.3 The Syntax of Partway Modiers` on p. 135 of the [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

and then

```
($ (A) !.5! (B) $)
```

to get the middle between node A and B.

Comment: It seems like in the new versions of the manual there is Euler tutorial and the calc explanation is missing.